# Unable to install Virtual Box Guest additions

Tags: virtualbox

Unable to install VirtualGuestAdditions in Linux (Tails Operating System)

[image: Virtual Box Guest Additions error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy Guest ISO file(inside virtual box installation folder) to your guest.
and mount the ISO file.

Ex:

sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/tecmint/Fedora-18-i386-DVD.iso /mnt/iso/

Open the folder and run the installation scripts.

Make sure your system is compatible with virtual box guest additions.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Finally, I figured it out. I can not mount Guesteditions.iso file in Tails OS. Because Tails OS loads from ISO image or USB stick and wipes it's data after every restart (literally wipes all data). If you unmount Tails OS iso file then virtual machine no longer works

Answer (score 0):

You should download the right version, like VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.32.iso. Here the 5.0.32 is same as your virtualbox's version.

After start your virtual system, you can select the iso to mount in the virtualbox's control menu.

Comment: maybe you need search VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED.

Comment: Finally, I figured it out. I can not mount Guesteditions.iso file in Tails OS. Because Tails OS loads from ISO image or USB stick and wipes it's data after every restart (literally wipes all data). If you unmount Tails OS iso file then virtual machine no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and worked for almost an hour, after downloading and building the iso for guest addition. This could be caused by either your dont have the optical drive, or you mount the ISO before you execute the command of [Device] [Insert]:

1. Make an 'empty' optical disk drive.
2. Run [Device] [Insert Guest Addition]
3. Then Ubuntu will look for c:\program files\Oracle.....(location of the Guest Addition ISO)

Remarks: look like if you pre-mount/pre-insert the ISO / virtual CD, then the error message will come out.

Answer (score 0):

In each version of VirtualBox this problem is resurrected and the solution is different every time.

Now (2019, virtualbox 6.0, Ubuntu 18), for Guest Additions to work, they require the gcc compiler, Perl, make, etc. And in Ubuntu they are no longer installed by default. Then, from inside the guest, install:

- sudo apt install build-essential
- From Nautilus, eject the Guest Additions disk
- Reboot
- Menu - Devices - Insert Guest Additions disc

And that's all.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going through this solution step by step:

Step 1:  `sudo su`

Step 2:  `cd /media`

Step 3:  `mkdir cdrom`

Step 4:  `mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`

Step 5:  `cd cdrom`

Step 6:  `sh VBoxLinux-Additions.run`

Just be patient as it takes some time and remember you are ***root***

In case it didn't work please follow this [link](https://superuser.com/a/1375272/714723) from SuperUser, hope it helps you.